# Launch pm2 as superuser

Tags: linux, node.js, sudo, pm2

I'm trying to launch node.js application with pm2. 
I've installed pm2: `sudo npm install pm2 -g`

Now, if I launch pm2 as non-root user it works fine.
But if I try to run: `sudo pm2 logs` I have an error: 
`pm2: command not found`

`pm2 logs` works fine

If I use a sh-script to launch: `sudo sh run.sh` there is another error in logs:

```
events.js:72         
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event               
^ Error: connect EACCES
```

How can I launch pm2 as super-user, to make sure that other users can launch and restart applications with `sudo pm2 monit` or `sudo pm2 restart appname` etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apparently `pm2` is not listed in the `PATH` for root.

Check if the `PATH` for non-root and root users are the same like this

```
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sh
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
```

if not add the missing path for `pm2` for root